# How to use RestKit for mapping source JSON to a structurally different model?

Tags: ios, json, mapping, restkit

I have a JSON in a fixed structure and a fixed data model with a different structure. For example for some attributes of objects in the source model I have to create a new object in the destination data model, one object for each attributes, some other objects in the source model I do not need in the destination data model. All in all I need to map the source model to a structurally different destination model, with different numbers and structure of objects. Is it possible with RestKit? What would be the best approach? I found  the RKValueTransformer class group that seems as a tool for such job, but as soon as I transform the top level object with my custom transform, I have to work with dictionaries. Is there any way to re-enter into the object mapping hierarchy from a block of a value transformer in the sense to be able to use other mappings for objects with known structure? Or are there any better way to do this?

Here is an example. Suppose I have the following JSON:

```
"label": {
  "title": "foo",
  "color": "red",
  "font": "times"
}
```

And I have to map it to the following objects:

```
@interface Label : NSObject {
  @property (strong) NSString* title;
  @property (strong) NSArray* attributes; // array of Attribute
}

@interface Attribute : NSObject {
  @property (strong) NSString* key;
  @property (strong) NSString* value;
}
```

In a way that the resulting objects would look like:

```
Label {
  title = @"foo",
  attributes = @[ 
    Attribute { key = @"color", value = @"red" },
    Attribute { key = @"font", value = @"times" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: That sucks as a mapping... Do you have a set list of attribute key names? Not convinced a value transformer is a sensible way to go, but you may need to add some unclean code to your data objects to mutate the data during mapping...

Comment: Yes, I know the possible attribute keys in advance. "Mutating the data" you mean to add some custom setter-like method to the data object that consumes a fragment of JSON as dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is outside of the standard scope of RestKit. Here's an idea of how you might go about achieving your requirement (I haven't tried it):

For each key/value pair that you want to map into an attribute, add a relationship mapping which goes from the source key to the matching destination key. This is where an unclean bit of code comes in as we need to intercept this key being set and add the provided attribute to the common array. It's possible that we may be able to use `setValue:forUndefinedKey:` - try that first as it minimises code. Check the type of the value, if it's an attribute, add it. If this doesn't work, look at adding a `set##KEY_NAME##:(Attribute *)` method.

The relationship mapping uses another mapping. That mapping needs to get the key and value for the attribute:

```
RKObjectMapping *attributeMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Attribute class]];
[attributeMapping addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute:@"key"];
[attributeMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"(key)": @"value" }];
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to `addAttributeMappingFromKeyOfRepresentationToAttribute`, I did not known it.